# Java - Decryption : javax.crypto.BadPaddingException

Tags: java, encryption

I get this warning:

javax.crypto.BadPaddingException: Given final block not properly padded. Such issues can arise if a bad key is used during decryption.

Any ideas what causes this? Here are my encryption and decryption code. I have looked at a variety of different answers on StackOverflow but I was unable to find one that actually works.

```
    private static Cipher ecipher;
private static Cipher dcipher;

private static SecretKey key;

public static void Menu() {
    try {

        // generate secret key using DES algorithm
        key = KeyGenerator.getInstance("DES").generateKey();

        ecipher = Cipher.getInstance("DES");
        dcipher = Cipher.getInstance("DES");

        // initialize the ciphers with the given key
        ecipher.init(Cipher.ENCRYPT_MODE, key);

        dcipher.init(Cipher.DECRYPT_MODE, key);

    } catch (NoSuchAlgorithmException e) {
        System.out.println("No Such Algorithm:" + e.getMessage());
        return;
    } catch (NoSuchPaddingException e) {
        System.out.println("No Such Padding:" + e.getMessage());
        return;
    } catch (InvalidKeyException e) {
        System.out.println("Invalid Key:" + e.getMessage());
        return;
    }
}

public static String encrypt(String WordToEncrypt) {

    Menu();
    try {

        // encode the string into a sequence of bytes using the named charset
        // storing the result into a new byte array. 
        byte[] utf8 = WordToEncrypt.getBytes("UTF8");

        byte[] enc = ecipher.doFinal(utf8);

        // encode to base64
        enc = BASE64EncoderStream.encode(enc);
        System.out.println(new String(enc));

        return new String(enc);

    } catch (Exception e) {

        e.printStackTrace();

    }
    return null;
}

public static String decrypt(String WordToDecrypt) {
    Menu();
    try {
        // decode with base64 to get bytes
        byte[] dec = BASE64DecoderStream.decode(WordToDecrypt.getBytes());
        byte[] utf8 = dcipher.doFinal(dec);
        return new String(utf8, "UTF8");
    } catch (Exception e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
    return null;

}
```

}

Comment: Do you encrypt and decrypt in one run (one time starting the Java runtime?) If not you are generating each time a new random key using `generateKey()` which of course breaks the encryption as it is random and therefore different to the key used for encryption.

Comment: Crypto anti-pattern: Cipher.getInstance("DES");. Always include the full algorithm/mode/padding specification. In this case you are probably getting a CBC mode algorithm, but you do nothing with the IV. Also, as the previous commenter noted, you generate a one key for encryption and a different one for decryption.  This looks like an attempt at copy&paste programming and that just doesn't work for crypto. The Java crypto architecture is unfortunately somewhat low level and thus requires a reasonable level of expertise to use.

Answer (score 0):

You call `Menu` once in the encryption code  and once in the decryption code. Since you generate the key randomly for both encryption and decryption, the key will differ and your code will fail.

Don't keep `Cipher` instances around, preferably not even in fields, but certainly not in class fields. DES is old; *too* old. Use AES - using DES isn't any easier than AES.